# FFmpeg exact output duration millisecond-precise

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running a simple cmd line with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav output.mp3
```

But the duration of the mp3 calculated with ffprobe is `0.05s`  more than the original file. I've tried several option and cmd line like `-write_xing 0` or forcing the output to be a specific duration but none of them worked. From ffprobe it looks like a few ms offset at the output start time. Why does it happen? Is it the mp3 encoding that pads the beginning of the file? How can I achieve an exact duration?

Here is the ffprobe of both input and output:

```
Input: Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.66.102
  Duration: 00:00:40.00, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s

Output:   Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
  Duration: 00:00:40.05, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.93
```

Comment: Not possible for AAC/MP3 output. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42410479/5726027 If you transcode back to WAV, you'll have your original duration.