# Batch merge audio files by specific timestamp without reencoding

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, concatenation, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to batch merge mp3 audio files where every single file has a specific start time. So below is the fluent-ffmpeg spawn I use right now to merge 3 files with each starting at respectively 200, 7400 and 10600.

```
ffmpeg -i firstFile.mp3 -i secondFile.mp3 -i thirdFile.mp3 -filter_complex 
[0]adelay=200[a0];[1]adelay=7400[a1];[2]adelay=10600[a2];[a0][a1] 
[a2]amix=inputs=3:dropout_transition=1000,volume=3 -f mp3 pipe:1
```

This works pretty good, except for longer files re-encoding makes the process take real long. So I wanted to do the same thing using concat demuxer. Since I already know how long each audio file is, I've put in silent audio files between them to create a delay until next audio file so it actually starts on the time position it is supposed to.

```
#concatfile.txt

file silence.mp3
outpoint 200
file firstFile.mp3
file silence.mp3
outpoint 1500
file secondFile.mp3
file silence.mp3
outpoint 2000
file thirdFile.mp3

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i concatfile.txt -c copy output.mp3
```

This solution also works okay when merging few files but when I merge higher count of files like 30 or 40 result file will have a slowly increasing synchronization problem where audio files actually start later than the start timestamps they are supposed to have.

Looks like an issue similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416110/ffmpeg-concat-video-and-audio-out-of-sync)

I'm open for any suggestion on solving the issue.

Comment: Sync problem with what? You only appear to have one stream in the output - do you mean speed or pitch changes?

Comment: an audio file that is supposed to start at lets say 0:30:25 starts at 0:30:26 and all other audios after that also have a delay, it is like on every concat operation there is an overflow of 0.02 seconds

Comment: so I guess the question is does the demux concat have milliseconds precision. Because for instance, if I concatenate 2 files of 0:01:00 and 0:01:20 duration the result often is something like 0:02:22.

Comment: Ok, this is not really an error, but a consequence of the audio codec. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42415886. I haven't tested this but you could try adding `inpoint 0.026` for all of the non-silent MP3s.

Comment: I've tried adding 0.026 but that didn't help either. I've also tried the inpoint with a one liner ffmpeg to test out. I did only put 2 audio files on the text file and concatenated them but resulting audio duration was the same as If I didn't include inpoint at all. So I don't know maybe I'm doing something wrong with the inpoints.

Comment: I've made the changes on the textfile with the `inpoint 0.026` but the output I get on that has the exact same duration when I didn't put it on the first place.